# Hotswapping CDs on Linux

Tags: wine, data-cd, hot-plug

Right now I'm trying to install Battlefield 2 from CD-ROM on my Linux computer (I know Battlefield 2 is a little old now but I couldn't care less). Of course, it needs to be run under Wine, and luckily for me Wine isn't the issue yet. The issue is that once the installer asks for Disk 2 to be inserted, it doesn't get detected. I know pretty confidently that the issue is that the second disk just isn't being recognized as a new disk somewhere in the kernel which causes big problem and that the issue is that the disk isn't being unmounted properly, but I can't unmount the disk properly, since that would require that the installer gets killed. I tried a bunch of AHCI and SCSI tricks, but to no avail. If lsblk can tell the disk is different, there should be a way to tell unaware parts of the system about it, but I'm not sure how. Help pls

Comment: Dump the disks as images, mount them as images (`-o loop`).

Comment: Does this help? https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2424 there's a detailed installation guide which addresses the multi-cdrom problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine has a `wine eject` command to address this. When it's time to switch disks, simply fire up another terminal and `wine eject`, then plug in the second disk.

It is noteworthy that the appropriate $WINEPREFIX must be set for this command to work properly.

Comment: I didn't read about this, I'll have to try it when I get back home! I'll get back to you soon